# Generating RDLC Report of General Ledger in C# windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation, sqlcedatareader

This is the screenshot I have taken from Accounting software and I want to create a similar type of report using C# Windows Form Application, I have a data against all account numbers, What I think of is running multiple quires for all account numbers and that is a lengthy process I am using MS SQL Compact Edition Database any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

General Ledger report screenshot from peach tree
[image]

Comment: Tell me there is not sensitive information in this screen shot? Additionally, you are not quite at the point of asking a question on stackoverflow. All you have at the moment is a statement of intent. Any solution will require multiple steps, or just suggestions, either way its not a good fit for the site in its current format

Comment: @TheGeneral This is dummy data that I have provided in the screenshot and I want simple solution to achieve this view, I have done it using multiple quires for each account number like 10000 and 10100 so for every account number I have to write separate quires for all. That s why i asked that if there is more efficient way to do that.